# How to listen an event on a new element inserted using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

In my backbone.js app, i insert an element in the dom :

```
newElement = $('<div id="resizable" class="resizable"><div class="close">x</div><input type="text" name="text_' + @count++ + '" /></div>');
@previewWrapper.append(newElement);
```

How can I listen the click event on the close button. Can i use the Events property of my view?

Maybe the better way to insert element is to create a specific backbone view and template, so i can listen events on it using the events property?

Thank you for you help and recommendations.

Comment: @Sebastin Do you face any issues by including close icon and the count inside the template for the respective model ( i mean the `x`  and `@count`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the events generated by the DOM element assigned to the view and its children, grandchildren, etc via the `events` -hash. So in the view where you insert these new elements you can do

```
events: {
  ...
  'eventType .close': 'callbackFuncName',
  ...
}
```

The events will bubble up to their parent DOM element.

If the elements you are inserting are to have even a little bit of functionality, I suggest creating a view that represents such an element so you maintain some separation of functionality.

hope this helps!

Comment: Oh great, didn't insert it in a backbone view but somewhere else on the DOM. So, it's maybe better to create a new View for this element?

Comment: yes, I don't recommend listening to events from DOM elements that are not children of the listening view's DOM element or the view's DOM element itself.